# Geting user id from Trello's API (client.js)

Tags: api, authentication, trello

I'm using Trello's client.js library to interact with their API. I'm calling `Trello.authorize();` to successfully authenticate the user. I can retrieve the authenticated user's token by calling `Trello.token();`.

I'm trying to figure out a way to grab the authenticated user's Trello id.

Any help?